# Can Nifi load data from DB2 to Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, db2, apache-nifi, db2-400

I am exploring options to load data from DB2 to Cassandra using open source tools. I read through some of the blogs and articles and found Nifi is one of the recommended tool. Need some inputs on whether Nifi could perform this job or any other better tool? Any other suggestions to load data? Like any native connector to pull data from DB2?? Many thanks in advance for help.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NiFi has a number of processors that allow you to pull from database tables using a JDBC driver, such as ExecuteSQL, QueryDatabaseTable, and GenerateTableFetch. As of NiFi 1.9.0, there is also a PutCassandraRecord processor so you can put your data directly into Cassandra (without having to write CQL).

Comment: Thanks Mattyb. Do i need to install or use any jar file for connecting to DB? I saw in one of the online forum about using a jar file called jr400T (if i remember correctly). I don't see this jar file in the library.

Comment: NiFi doesn't come with any JDBC drivers, you have to download them yourself (check here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866) and specify the location of the JAR(s) in the DBCPConnectionPool

Comment: For Cassandra do i need to create a table or will Nifi create a table and load it on fly? Because my table has over 100 columns.

Comment: Thank mattyb for your help

Comment: When i am loading from ExecuteSQL to PutCassandraRecord it is throwing the error - expected 4 or 0 byte int (5) error. Any other processor  to be added between ESQL and PutCassandraRecord? Or should i change all the int to double in Cassandra table? My workflow is ESQL --> PutCassandraRecord. Do i need to try something like this - ESQL -> SplitAvro --> ConvertAvrotoJson --> ConvertJsontoSQL --> ReplaceText --> PutCassandra